# Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA)

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I am currently working on an indexing program. I recently added during my Regex searched through files a way to detect duplicates of the Regex inside the same file.

The problem is I get:

> Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA) mode before OLE calls can be made. Ensure that your Main function has STAThreadAttribute marked on it.

When I call my export function which would write the duplicates to a file. However I use the export functions many times in other parts of the program and I have never encountered this problem before.

To put short what I do is:

1. **FormStats.vb**:

   1.1. Regex Search through `BackGroundWorker()`

   1.2. Store Duplicates if any

   1.3. Call on `BackGroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted` to `ExportDoublon()`
2. **FileHandler.vb**

   2.1. Call on `WriteDoublon()` To `exportToWord()`
3. **Exporter.vb**

   3.1. `exportToWord()`

Line where the error appears:

```
Clipboard.SetText(table)
```

The way the class is called from **FileHandler.vb**:

```
Public Sub WriteDoublon(ByVal CurrentDoub As List(Of Doublon))
    Dim dgv As New DataGridView
    dgv.Columns.Add("Name", "Name")
    dgv.Columns.Add("Fiche", "Fiche")
    For Each doublee As Doublon In CurrentDoub
        dgv.Rows.Add(doublee.Name, doublee.Ficher)
        dgv.Rows.Add("**********", "**********")
    Next
    Dim exp As New Exporter
    Dim prog As New ProgressBar
    exp.exportToWord(dgv, AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "Exports\Doublon.docx", prog)
End Sub
```

The place where **FileHandler.WriteDoublon()** is called **FormStats.vb**:

```
Public Sub ExportDoublon()
    Dim fl As New FileHandler
    fl.WriteDoublon(Doub)
End Sub
```

Class where the error appears **Exporter.vb**:

```
Public Sub exportToWord(ByVal dgv As DataGridView, ByVal pather As String, ByVal progresser As ProgressBar)    
    Dim oWord As Word.Application = DirectCast(CreateObject("Word.Application"), Word.Application)
    Dim oDoc As Word.Document = oWord.Documents.Add()
    oWord.Visible = False    
    Dim headers = (From ch In dgv.Columns
                   Let header = DirectCast(DirectCast(ch, DataGridViewColumn).HeaderCell, DataGridViewColumnHeaderCell)
                   Select header.Value).ToArray()
    Dim headerText() As String = Array.ConvertAll(headers, Function(v) v.ToString)

    Dim items() = (From r In dgv.Rows
                   Let row = DirectCast(r, DataGridViewRow)
                   Where Not row.IsNewRow
                   Select (From cell In row.Cells
                           Let c = DirectCast(cell, DataGridViewCell)
                           Select c.Value).ToArray()).ToArray()    
    Dim table As String = String.Join(vbTab, headerText) & Environment.NewLine
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    For Each a In items
        Dim t() As String = Array.ConvertAll(a, Function(v) v.ToString)
        table &= String.Join(vbTab, t) & Environment.NewLine
        progresser.Value = i * 100 / items.Count
        i = i + 1
    Next
    table = table.TrimEnd(CChar(Environment.NewLine))
    '--ERROR HERE
    Clipboard.SetText(table)
    '#############    
    Dim oTable As Word.Table = oDoc.Tables.Add(oDoc.Bookmarks.Item("\endofdoc").Range, items.Count + 1, headers.Count)    
    oTable.Range.Paste()    
    'make the first row bold, fs 14 + change textcolor
    oTable.Rows.Item(1).Range.Font.Bold = &H98967E
    oTable.Rows.Item(1).Range.Font.Size = 14
    oTable.Rows.Item(1).Range.Font.Color = Word.WdColor.wdColorWhite    
    'change backcolor of first row
    oTable.Rows.Item(1).Range.Shading.Texture = Word.WdTextureIndex.wdTextureNone
    oTable.Rows.Item(1).Alignment = Word.WdAlignmentTabAlignment.wdCenter
    oTable.Rows.Item(1).Range.Shading.ForegroundPatternColor = Word.WdColor.wdColorAutomatic
    oTable.Rows.Item(1).Range.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = Word.WdColor.wdColorPaleBlue    
    'set table borders
    With oTable.Range.Tables(1)
        With .Borders(Word.WdBorderType.wdBorderLeft)
            .LineStyle = Word.WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleSingle
            .LineWidth = Word.WdLineWidth.wdLineWidth100pt
            .Color = Word.WdColor.wdColorAutomatic
        End With
        With .Borders(Word.WdBorderType.wdBorderRight)
            .LineStyle = Word.WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleSingle
            .LineWidth = Word.WdLineWidth.wdLineWidth100pt
            .Color = Word.WdColor.wdColorAutomatic
        End With
        With .Borders(Word.WdBorderType.wdBorderTop)
            .LineStyle = Word.WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleSingle
            .LineWidth = Word.WdLineWidth.wdLineWidth100pt
            .Color = Word.WdColor.wdColorAutomatic
        End With
        With .Borders(Word.WdBorderType.wdBorderBottom)
            .LineStyle = Word.WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleSingle
            .LineWidth = Word.WdLineWidth.wdLineWidth100pt
            .Color = Word.WdColor.wdColorAutomatic
        End With
        With .Borders(Word.WdBorderType.wdBorderHorizontal)
            .LineStyle = Word.WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleSingle
            .LineWidth = Word.WdLineWidth.wdLineWidth050pt
            .Color = Word.WdColor.wdColorAutomatic
        End With
        With .Borders(Word.WdBorderType.wdBorderVertical)
            .LineStyle = Word.WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleSingle
            .LineWidth = Word.WdLineWidth.wdLineWidth050pt
            .Color = Word.WdColor.wdColorAutomatic
        End With
        .Borders(Word.WdBorderType.wdBorderDiagonalDown).LineStyle = Word.WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleNone
        .Borders(Word.WdBorderType.wdBorderDiagonalUp).LineStyle = Word.WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleNone
        .Borders.Shadow = False
    End With
    oDoc.SaveAs2(pather)
    oDoc.Close()
    oDoc = Nothing
    oWord.Quit()
    oWord = Nothing
    GC.Collect()
    GC.WaitForFullGCComplete()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your call to `exportToWord` is apparently running on a thread configured as `Threading.ApartmentState.MTA` (Backgroundworker threads are `Threading.ApartmentState.MTA`). Often when you access a control such as this methods does for the datagridview, you will receive a `Cross-thread operation not valid` error.  However this check is run only for such accesses that require the control's `Handle` property; in this case you are accessing data information from `dgv` that does not trigger this check.

If you add the following pointless statement to the beginning of `exportToWord`, an error should be thrown.

```
Dim handle As IntPtr = dgv.Handle
```

Access to the `Clipboard` must be done from a `Threading.ApartmentState.STA` thread and the UI thread is such a thread. The proper way to do this is to `Invoke` method on the UI thread where `Me` is the Form instance:

```
Me.Invoke(New Action(Of DataGridView, String, ProgressBar)(AddressOf exp.exportToWord), New Object(){dgv, AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "Exports\Doublon.docx", prog})
```

versus the current

```
exp.exportToWord(dgv, AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "Exports\Doublon.docx", prog)
```